# Detecting curl can connect to intranet website or abort

Tags: bash, curl

so i have a bash script which is downloading couple of files from my company intranet. Hence, user has to run it either connected to company network via lan or vpn.

How, do i check if curl could not connect to the intranet website and download required file and abort in that case.

Answer (score 0):

`curl` has two options, `--connect-timeout` and `--max-time` which can be used for handling connection failures and slow response from server.

See this post for details:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94604/does-curl-have-a-timeout

Comment: well how do i handle in two cases: 1. server responded as cannot connect within specified time which is less than connect-timeout  2. say timeout occurs then how do i handle that in my script?

Comment: I think `curl`'s exit code will indicate the situation.  See https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl